# applying euclidian distance formular in PHP

Tags: php

Here is my furmula implementation for euclidian equation.

```
    $i = 0;
    $min = 0;

    while ($row = @mysqli_fetch_array($result))

    {

        $pcount = $row['pcount'];

        $ncount = $row['ncount'];

        echo "pcount is $pcount<br/>";

        echo "ncount is $ncount<br/></br>";
        $a[$i] = $pcoutn ;
        $b[$i] = $pcoutn ;
        while ($row = @mysqli_fetch_array($result))

        {

            $a[$j] =    $row['pcount']; 
            $b[$j] =    $row['ncount'];
            $diff = sqrt(($a[$i] - $a[$j])^2 + ($b[$i] - $b[$j])^2 )
            $j= $j + 1;
            echo "$diff <br>";
        }               
        $i = $i + 1;        


    }
```

What is syntax error?

Error is : `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$j' (T_VARIABLE)`

Comment: You are missing a semicolon after `$diff = sqrt(($a[$i] - $a[$j])^2 + ($b[$i] - $b[$j])^2 )`

Comment: `^` is the [`xor`](http://www.php.net/manual/language.operators.bitwise.php) operator. So even without the syntax error, your endresult will be wrong. Use [`pow`](http://php.net/manual/function.pow.php) instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have skipped `;` on line

```
$diff = sqrt(($a[$i] - $a[$j])^2 + ($b[$i] - $b[$j])^2 )
```

Use

```
$diff = sqrt(($a[$i] - $a[$j])^2 + ($b[$i] - $b[$j])^2 );
```